# Calling a Method in a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im learning angularjs, so i started playing around with yts database movies api, it was working well untill i notice i needed different functionalities on my home page, for example 'latest movies', 'best rated'.
So i created some methods, where each method is related with latest movies, or upcomming movies and so on. But i cant make the code fire up, my init method.

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', 
    ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home',{
        templateUrl: 'assets/template/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })  
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home' 
    });
});

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.upcomingList = [];
    $scope.latestMovies = [];

    //initilize 
     $scope.init = function() {
            $scope.getCommingSoon();
            $scope.getLatestMovies();

        };


    $scope.getLatestMovies = function(){
        $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://yts.to/api/v2/list_movies.json'
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers){
            $scope.latestMovies = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers){

        });
    }



    $scope.getCommingSoon = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://yts.to/api/v2/list_upcoming.json'
            })
            .success(function(data, status, headers){
                $scope.comingsoon = data;

            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers){

            });
        };


});
```

home.html

```
 <div ng-init="init();" class="container home-content">

 <div  ng-repeat="movie in getLatestMovies | limitTo: 4" class="browse-movie-wrap col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
                       <p>{{latestMovies}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use ng-repeat="movie in latestMovies | limitTo: 4"

Comment: @MaheSirius thanks a lot, stupid of me, one last question, in my ng-repeat i have to put "movie in latestMovies.data.movies" because the json is a multimensional array, is this the right way doing it or i have to make this change in the controller?

Comment: Ya you can do so or directly assigning $scope=data.data.movies would be better. I will post this as answer pls accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not rendered because you have used getLatestMovies in ngRepeat instead of latestMovies, and also no need to use ngInit.

You can call a method directly inside ngRepeat.

```
<div class="container home-content">

 <div  ng-repeat="movie in getLatestMovies() | limitTo: 4" class="browse-movie-wrap col-xs-10 col-sm-5">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sirius'a answer, you need to use `movie in latestMovies` instead. 
The reason behind is:

1) the attribute in ngRepeat directive only takes expressions, it does not evaluate the expression.

2) AngularJs is a Model-View framework. When you work with Angular, really try to think in angular. The way that you put your data into a model is all set in a controller. The view is a window to show your organized data (model) in html tags. only certain event-triggering directives such as ngClick evaluates your method in your controller in order to trigger the model change event, which is watched by `$watch` the whole time.

Anyway, in your case, you really just need to use a model rather than using a method in your scope because the view needs to bind a model.